# What was Roddenberry's first idea for Spock?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, spock

From the [Development of Spock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development_of_Spock) article on Wikipedia (emphasis by me):

> However, he was still apprehensive as he wanted to have a serious acting career and did not want to be made to look foolish by playing an alien with pointy ears and other as-then undetermined makeup. When the character was included in the original 1964 pitch, Roddenberry wrote that the character was "**probably half Martian**, he has a slightly reddish complexion and semi-pointed ears". Early versions had the character ingest energy through a plate in his stomach. Writer Samuel A. Peeples told Roddenberry these attributes made Spock too alien, and suggested "**he should at least be half-human** and have the problems of both sides", believing the human traits made the character more interesting and able to comment on the human condition more believably. **Spock's home planet was changed** because Roddenberry thought if the show was a success, humans might actually walk on Mars during the series' run. The eventual logical nature of Spock was originally written into the character Number One as portrayed by Majel Barrett. It was not until the second pilot that this was included as one of Spock's traits.

So, the timeline goes something like

- Roddenberry wants to make a half Martian Spock, other half unspecified in the article.
- Peeples suggest to make Spock half Human
- Martian is changed to Vulcan

What was Roddenberry's initial intention for Spock's other half to be?

Comment: Human still, I'd imagine; Peeple's suggestion was likely to stray away from him being _too_ alien. [Star Trek is...](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_is...) gives the full initial description.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot But then, Peeples suggestion wouldn't make sense?!

Comment: I think Peeple's is just saying that they shouldn't make Spock extremely alien and bring him more closer to humans. Spock could always have been part human; just that the alien side was a lot more prominent. But given the context here we can interpret it both ways I agree.

Comment: I vaguely remember *Memories* saying he was also supposed to have small horns, playing up on the devilish appearance.

Comment: there isn't much in the orignal pitch other than the 'satanic' looking Spock being 'probably half-Martian' - https://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/reports/40_years/trek_pitch.pdf <-- direct link to the document referenced in @TheLethalCarrot's comment

Comment: @NKCampbell With the pitch not describing another half and as we're human, it can safely be assumed that Spock was intended to be half Martian, half Human. Would you formulate it into an answer?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot was first w/ the original pitch doc :)